# How can you create text as a png file to minimize file size?

Tags: images, png, transparency

I've seen this trick on lots of websites, but I don't know how I could create this myself easily. It's basically text or a logo which is saved on a transparent background with a small border, to minimize the file size.

---

For example on [**Postmarkapp**](http://postmarkapp.com/), they have this transparent logo, with a yellow border:

[image: Postmark logo]

and there are a lot more of these examples on the web.

---

What's an easy way to create such a png file with a small border so your text or logo will seamlessly blend into the background color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something couldn't you just use Photoshop to create the image with a transparent background and then use CSS to position it appropriately (through various different techniques)?

Comment: :\ Just found the expand selection option in Photoshop, nevermind

Comment: For seamless edges: use the **Save for Web...** option and select a **Matte** color to blend semi-transparent anti-aliased pixels with the background color you plan to use.

Comment: @danlefree, Thanks, that's where this question was about, how I could easily get a small border at places where the image was semi-transparent

Comment: Pretty much all desktop browsers support alpha channel transparency these days, so you don't even need to use a matte color. But I don't know how things are with mobile browsers.